# Card stack like controls to display screens

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard

I like how RTM has these stackable cards, where you can just drag the 'card' to the left and it drag it back to the right with ease.

Is this something you have to create using some animation framework?  It really makes jumping between screens fast and effecient.

Can someone lead me to some tutorial or something that can teach me how to make these types of controls?  They call it 'card stack'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for: [StackScrollView](https://github.com/aaronbrethorst/StackScrollView)